# Importerror on prawcore using crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron, linux-mint

So I've written my own wallpaper changer using python and praw to pull images down from reddit. It works great when called from the command line. My issue is with crontab. I modified the crontab using `sudo crontab -e` and placed this inside

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/doubt_even/RWPC  >> /var/log/wallpaper_output.log 2>&1`

This returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/doubt_even/RWPC", line 9, in <module> 
    import praw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .reddit import Reddit  # NOQA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from prawcore import (Authorizer, DeviceIDAuthorizer, ReadOnlyAuthorizer,
ImportError: No module named prawcore
```

My shebang is #!/usr/bin/python. I've tried appending the path to prawcore inside the script using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prawcore/')
```

I've noticed that my script does not successfully change the wallpaper if I run it using the sudo prefix from the command line. I tried putting the script in the cron.hourly and the same crontab entry into the regular `crontab -e`. The output file does not work when I put it into `crontab -e` so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
doubt_even@mint ~ $ sudo /usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf-1.13-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygeoip-0.3.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

doubt_even@mint~ $/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf-1.13-py2.7.egg','/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygeoip-0.3.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

doubt_even@mint ~ $ /usr/bin/python -c "import prawcore; print prawcore.__file__"
/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prawcore/__init__.pyc
```

I also tried a explicitly stating the PYTHONPATH, but I've read that's not the best solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: - Does this directory exist: `/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prawcore/`? - Does it have a `__init__.py` in it? - _I also tried a explicitly stating the PYTHONPATH, _ Could you explain how?

Comment: Also... it would be useful if you paste the result of running this in your console 1) `/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` 2) `/usr/bin/python -c "import prawcore; print prawcore.__file__"`

Comment: It does exist and contain the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I updated the post to include that info

Comment: Thanks, we are almost there, please add the output of `sudo /usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`. I think you'll see the answer by your self (hint: I expect __not__ to see `/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in the output)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I guess what I really want to see is the pythonpath for root user (with in turns is the pythonpath for root's crontab). The correct command should be to run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path" __as the root user__, not just with sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the interpreter to find the module, the directory **containing** the module (i.e., not the module itself) should be listed on the `PYTHONPATH`.

#### Solution 1:

Run with root's `crontab` (as in `sudo crontab -e`), and inside your script:

```
# let the interpreter find prawcore
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```

#### Solution 2:

Set `PYTHONPATH` for crontab environment:

`$ sudo crontab -e`

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/doubt_even/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/doubt_even/RWPC  >> /var/log/wallpaper_output.log 2>&1
```

> I also tried a explicitly stating the PYTHONPATH, but I've read that's not the best solution.

I've used this approach in the past, never saw any inconvinients. May be you can share.

#### Solution 3:

Run with doubt_even's `crontab` (as in `crontab -e`)

> ...the output file does not work when I put it into crontab -e

you could solve this issue by writng to another directory where your regular user has write permissions, as in

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/doubt_even/RWPC  >> /home/doubt_even/.wallpaper_output.log 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you, solution 1 worked for getting rid of the import error.